# I have created a vector of structs.How do I remove elements from a vector of structures?Using vector.erase() does not seem to work properly

Tags: c++, vector, struct, structure

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout; using std::endl;
using std::vector; using std::string;

struct Person{
    string name;
    string surname;
    int age;
};


int main(){
    vector<Person> parr1 = {{"John", "Cooper", 32},
                                {"Theo", "Parrot", 23},
                                {"Kim", "Colbert", 53}};



    int i=0;
    parr1.erase(parr1.begin()+0);
    for (const auto &arr : parr1) {
       
        cout << i << endl;
      
        cout << "Name: " << arr.name << endl
             << "Surname: " << arr.surname << endl
             << "Age: " << arr.age << endl;
         i++;  
         
    }
    cout<<parr1[2].age<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code , while accessing an out-of-bound element , it gives no error as such. Also what happens to a pointer pointing to an element of a struct object that is no longer in the vector (removed using erase)?Do I need a destructor for struct?

```
0
Name: Theo
Surname: Parrot
Age: 23
1
Name: Kim
Surname: Colbert
Age: 53
53
```

This is output I got ,which is not what I expected.I am new to C++.Please if anyone can explain.

Comment: No you do not need an explicit destructor for your struct (one is implicitly created for you that will call the destructors of your strings). Also the output is correct. You removed the first struct from the vector with your erase call, and then the struct with Theo will be the first one. Replace `parr1[2]` with `parr1.get_at(2)` and you will get an error.

Comment: "while accessing an out-of-bound element , it gives no error" - No, you don't get an error. It is simply [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and you have a broken/buggy program on your hands. C++ doesn't hold your hand. It it up to *you* to know all the rules and make sure you don't break them.

Comment: @PepijnKramer the function is simply called [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), not `get_at`.

Comment: In general, the **programmer** is responsible for making sure a vector's index is within range.  Using `parr1[2]` when `2` is out of range is **undefined behavior**... it might crash (if you are lucky), it might seem to work (if you are unlucky), it may email your browser history to your grandmother and then format your hard drive.

Comment: @fabian yes slip of the mind ;)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Look at `parr1.size()` before and after the call to `erase`.

Answer (score 1):

> Using vector.erase() does not seem to work properly

On what basis you have concluded this?

Your program is erasing the first element of the vector `parr1`. After erasing, when reading the elements of `parr1`, the output shows remaining elements of the `parr1` vector and not the one which has been erased. So, vector modifier erase is working as expected. You need to educate yourself more on [Vector Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

After erasing the first element, the `parr1` vector contain `2` elements which can be accessed via index `0` and `1`. When your program attempting to access element at index `2` (`parr1[2]`) which is a non existent element, it land up in UB territory.

From [vector operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) *[emphasis added]*:

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. **No bounds checking is performed**.

> Notes
> ... Accessing a nonexistent element through this operator is **undefined behavior**.